# Android Button Response Time

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-button, lag

So I've created a simple soundboard app in Android Studio and run it using ADB to test it on my phone. It works perfectly fine but my issue is **when I tap on a button to play a sound clip there is a second delay before I can press it again and here the sound**. I would like to be able to **press the button as quickly as I want** and have it play the sound **with as little as delay as possible**.

Another issue I have with the button is that I'd like for **it to stop playing one sound when if I press another button**.

All I'm using right now is the `Mediaplayer class` and `setOnClickListener`. It's very simple not many lines of code. I feel like I've attempted to look into this in the documentation but I'm not sure if my questions are worded correctly so any suggestions on more  detailed questions I could search online myself would be appreciated.

I'm not sure if this is a problem caused by ADB or using my device that creates this lag so any personal experience would be greatly appreciated as well.

******EDIT******
For those asking for code.

```
    //set up the button sound
    MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    //button 1
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mpButtonClick.start();
        }
    });
```

I've got 5 buttons and they all work like this. I just play sounds from a resource folder and 4 of the clips are less than 2 seconds long.

Since I'm new to this I'm unaware of asynctask and SoundPool I'll look into those right now.

********EDIT 2**********

So after doing some research I've decided SoundPool will most likely be what best suited for what I need. But I've seen that it creates issues for others who develop with it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484574/how-bad-is-android-soundpool-what-alternative-to-use) and on the Web in general. I also am not using ogg files which people say are more likely to work with SoundPool across different devices.

asynctask sounds like it could get the job done but I don't believe that it's intended to use in that way.

I also download six apps from the app store that I felt I would like mine to resemble and the one that was the best wasn't developed in an android environment but with the Unity engine. And since I have a little experience with that as well I believe I'll go that route thank you all.

Comment: I'm not very well versed on playing media with Android, but would running the sound in an asynctask possibly solve this issue?

Comment: Please post your code so we know what you've already tried.

Comment: Android is sadly known for its laggy audio response.

Comment: @Frank There are other soundboards on the Play Store that mimic the behavior he desires, so I think it's still doable.

Comment: Maybe, by using the SoundPool, which preloads the samples in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SoundPool` instead... you can pre-load the sounds and it'll let you have overlapping sounds.

More [information here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13001474/1715829).